# Migration in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting an error while migrating my tables. 
the error says

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'json null,
>   `start_date` date not null, `end_date` date not null, `status` enum(''
>   at line 1 (SQL: create table `modules` (`id` int unsigned not null
>   auto_increment primary key, `title` varchar(191) not null,
>   `description` text not null, `image` blob null, `resources` json null,
>   `start_date` date not null, `end_date` date not null, `status`
>   enum('pending', 'start', 'completed') not null default 'pending',
>   `user_id` int not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at`
>   timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

my table have following values:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->binary('image')->nullable();
            $table->json('resources')->nullable();
            $table->date('start_date');
            $table->date('end_date');
           $table->ENUM('status',['pending','start','completed'])->default('pending');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

this is my model code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class modules extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'title', 'description','image','resources', 'start_date','end_date','status','user_id',
        ];
    }
```

can anyone have the solution for this??

Comment: post your model code

Comment: i did post it, now can you help me out

Comment: check your MariaDB version.  From the MariaDB documentation, "The JSON alias was added in MariaDB 10.2.7. This was done to make it possible to use JSON columns in statement based replication from MySQL to MariaDB and to make it possible for MariaDB to read mysqldumps from MySQL."

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/

Comment: What version of MariaDB are you using?

Comment: Also add your Laravel Version to your question.

Comment: Have a look at this issue at github. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13622#issuecomment-396245375

Comment: Please add `Mysql` and `Laravel` version you are using.

Comment: It would be polite to accept an answer if any of them helped you

Answer (score 3):

As of Laravel, the `$table->json()` method will try to create an actual JSON field in the database. However, the JSON field was not added to MySQL until MySQL `5.7.8`.

Therefore, if you're using a version of MySQL previous to `5.7.8`, you need to just create it as a text field

MariaDB new version supported JSON. (Alpha version. Not recommended by Maria to production server. Only testing.)

MariaDB 10.1 do not support JSON

Answer (score 3):

The earlier version of maria db does not support json field type, see the link, https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-with-mariadb-10-2/

Please verify your mariadb version.

Answer (score 1):

May be adding the `$casts` class property will fix your problem.

```
class modules extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'resources' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

[Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) is something that may help you.